# "RSNNS" package doesn't allow me to use CARET's train function

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret, training-data

So far I was using the CARET package with RandomForest for my training.

I use CARET's `train` function with cross validation and all is working well.

That is until I wanted to try using neural network and uploaded the RSNNS package. Now, whenever I'm trying to use train (with my old rf algorithms) I get the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("train") : 
>     no applicable method for 'train' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

Is that bug? Why RSNNS causes that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `RSNNS::train()` is masking `caret::train()` because the RSNNS version was loaded after caret. Fix the problem by calling `caret::train()` with the `packageName::function()` syntax.

```
library(caret)
library(RSNNS)

library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)

inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = .75, list=FALSE)
training <- Sonar[inTraining,]
testing <- Sonar[-inTraining,]
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                           number = 3)
# error because RSNNS::train does not work like caret::train()
system.time(fit <- train(Class ~ ., method="rf",data=Sonar,trControl = fitControl))
# correct by calling caret::train()
system.time(fit <- caret::train(Class ~ ., method="rf",data=Sonar,trControl = fitControl))
fit
```

...and the output:

```
> system.time(fit <- train(Cx=Sonar[,-61],y=Sonar[,61], method="rf",data=Sonar,trControl = fitControl))
Error in UseMethod("train") : 
  no applicable method for 'train' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
Timing stopped at: 0.033 0 0.034
> # correct by calling caret::train()
> system.time(fit <- caret::train(x=Sonar[,-61],y=Sonar[,61], method="rf",data=Sonar,trControl = fitControl))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.888   0.069   3.981 
> fit
Random Forest 

208 samples
 60 predictor
  2 classes: 'M', 'R' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (3 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 139, 138, 139 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  Accuracy   Kappa    
   2    0.8175983  0.6292393
  31    0.7645963  0.5249374
  60    0.7694272  0.5336925

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 2.
>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! I wonder why it is not documented anywhere.

Comment: @Mark2Bra - This is at least a 15 year old problem, based on the [r help mailing list from 2002](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-April/020891.html). The solution of using the `packageName::function()` syntax has been documented in multiple places, such as this post on the [UCLA Institute for Digital Research & Education](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-does-r-handle-overlapping-object-names/) website.

Answer (score 0):

When loading packages, there's a warning:

```
> library(dplyr)

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
    filter, lag
The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

>

> library(MASS)

Attaching package: ‘MASS’
The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:
    select

>
```

1. When loading dplyr `stats::filter()`, `stats::lag()`, `base::intersect()`, `base::setdiff()`, `base::setequal()`, `base::union()` were masked.
2. `MASS::select()` overrides `dplyr::select()`.

Personal note: I believe the ideal would be always evoke functions using `packageName::function()` format, specially if you are wrangling data, plus, it makes easier to others catch up with the functions were actually used.